# how to add the logo into csv file using ECSVExport in yii?

Tags: php, yii

```
Yii::import('application.extensions..ECSVExport');
$filename = 'filename.csv';

$csv = new ECSVExport($sheet_generation);
$csv->setOutputFile($outputFile);
$imageUrl = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/themes/optisol/images/resign-icon.png'; 
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year); 
$heading="Attendance  for 01"."-".$month."-".$year." To ".$num."-".$month."-".$year." ";
$content=$heading;
$content = $content.$csv->toCSV(); 
Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($filename, $content, "text/csv", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. Not in the way you asked, actually.

A CSV is a text file, and therefore cannot have embedded images like a word processor document can.

If we want the image in the file, you will have to put the file name in the document. Then, the person reading the document can decide what to do with the file name.

A file will look this:

```
id, name, image, email
1,'Tom', 'image1.png', 'user1@domain.com'
1,'Jones', 'image2.png', 'user2@domain.com'
```